# Lookup Field that is a Picture (Signature)

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-office

I am following the directions from this post: https://sharepointprojectbrad.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-word-2013-documents-from-sharepoint-2013-list-items/

I am creating Word Docs based on Custom List Data and this is working just fine. I am using SharePoint 2010 Workflow and the process works great - with one exception:

I need to have one of the fields to be a picture from a Picture Library. These pictures are actually captured signatures that need to be added to the Word Docs. Is there a simple way to accomplish this within the same or similar process I am currently using?